# Django unittest the filter function

Tags: django, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following problem:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToMany(Bar)

# in a function somewhere else
def bla(bars):
    return Foo.objects.filter(bars__in=bars)
```

I want to test if the `.filter()` is called with the given parameter when I call `bla()`.

I wrote the test like this:

```
@patch('my_module.models.Foo')
def test_bla(self, FooMock):
    Foo.objects.filter = Mock()
    foo([1, 2])
    Foo.objects.filter.assert_called_with(bars__in=[1, 2])
```

It fails with `Not called`. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Could someone help me doing it the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is where you're patching. This walks you through a solution to your problem pretty well, I think:

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/

Comment: Thank you very much! My test is still failing, but now the patch is working. For others having the same problem: the bla() method was in a module called 'filters'. When I do @patch('filters.Foo'), then the patch works. But you could read the article which Adam posted ;)